# Are CentOS programs compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, compatibility, rpm

It's a long story, but it ends with me having Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Compaq Evo D500 computer and a bunch of CentOS programs on a thumb drive.

I was just wondering if these would be compatible with Ubuntu. I usually like to ask a question before I possibly crash my system.

Comment: Better idea would be searching them in Ubuntu repositories , or asking for help here for its  alternatives ( which would be very rare).

Comment: Do you mean "rpm" installers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short Maybe.  CentOS is an operating system that is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  While Ubuntu is based on Debian.

Package will not be portable between them. However systems are almost the same, software developed for one can usually easily be compiled for the other, it just has to be compiled and packaged a little differently.

> But using Alien you probably can.  Alien is a program that converts
>   between Red Hat rpm, Debian deb, Stam‐pede slp, Slackware tgz, and
>   Solaris pkg file formats. If you want to    use a package from another
>   linux distribution than the one you have installed on your system, you
>   can use alien to convert it to your pre‐ferred package format and
>   install it. It also supports LSB packages.<sup>1</sup>

To install it, you can do so from USC

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: Ubuntu Manuals</sup>

***P.S. Alien probably will not work with everything.  Make sure you test before attempting.***

Answer (score 1):

This is a useful link to use alien package converting tool

http://www.howtoforge.com/converting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien

I hope this will help you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. Your suggestion is acknowledged. :)